# How call Ruby's internal C methods in Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby

I'm trying to create a hash from an array and the documentation for http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.src/M000744.html shows an internal ruby method called ary_make_hash. The source uses this to diff arrays. The relevant line in the source is:  ary_make_hash(to_ary(ary2), 0);

Is there a way to access the ary_make_hash function and other internal Ruby functions from inside Ruby? I ask since I'm trying to convert a huge array to a hash and I'd love to use the built in C methods since they're so much faster. (FYI I can see the speed difference by subtracting two arrays, which internally invokes the converter method). Thanks for any thoughts.

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general if it's not in ruby.h, then it's not a "public" api
looking for a method called rb_xxx might also help.
GL.

Comment: Is "GL" short for "Good luck"?

Answer (score 1):

Are neither of these variations sufficiently fast? You're not doing very much in Ruby at all, but relying on the built in array-to-hash conversion.

```
a1 = [[:a,1],[:b,2],[:c,3]]
h1 = Hash[a2]
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3} 

a2 = a1.flatten
h2 = Hash[*a2]
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to take your idea and run it to see how fast it is since my array doesn't have a 'value' for each key.  My input is an array of 100 million strings. The goal of converting it to a hash is to use the has_key? method as a fast lookup (this is my read of how ruby's array diff method works). With both of the suggestions above, I couldn't find a way to make a default value for the hash that was fast. Creating this via an iterator, e.g. array.each{|a| hash[a] = 0} was fast at first (500,000 keys per second) but then fell to single digit thousands.

Comment: @rhh How about `Hash[ array.zip( [true]*array.length ) ]`? My machine can convert an array of 1,000,000 7-character strings into a hash in just over a second, and 10,000,000 8-character strings in 12.6 seconds. (It takes 466MB of real RAM and 2.8GB of virtual memory for the array of strings alone, and another 1.3GB of real RAM and 1.3GB of virtual memory to create the hash. Is your speed decline possibly you running out of memory?)

Answer (score 0):

That function is static, which, according to this: http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/SYNTAX/static.htm

means that it can't be referenced from outside the array.c file.

So in order to use it, you'd have to actually hack the source.